# How can 24 V (two 12 V batteries) x 100 A power a 5 kVA (or 4000 W) inverter?

Tags: batteries, inverter

I am a beginner at this. I know that energy cannot be created nor destroyed. I know you can't use 3 kVA inverter to run a 5 kVA dynamo (assuming I want it that way). Why then is 2400 W (12 V x 2 x 100 A) able to power some 5 kVA (4000 W with 0.8 power factor) inverters? Is there anything I don't understand?

Comment: Why? It won't happen. Someone has miscalculated or is lying basically.

Comment: Andy aka, there are even 5.5kva inverters that are 24v. I am trying to understand how it became possible. Haven't bought one but it is almost sold everywhere.

Comment: Maybe someone is confused between 100A and 100Ah. There isn't really any such thing as a 100A battery but 100Ah is common. Then the answer would be : For less than half an hour. (And practically, 15 mins max if you want the batteries to live more than a few cycles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most batteries are able to supply far more output current than the "nominal" value you find in data sheets.  In fact some will supply nearly "infinite" current until they destroy themselves.

As far are your 100A batteries supplying enough input to an inverter to generate 5KVA there are two possibilities that come to mind:

1. The inverter has the CAPACITY to generate 5KVA but in this application it's only producing 2.4 KVA so the batteries are able to supply the demand.
2. The batteries are, in fact, supplying MORE than 100A each and the inverter is able to product its 5 KVA output, for a while at least.

But the fundamental question that you seem to be asking is: "How can I get MORE than 2400W out of a 24V 100A battery system?"

The answer to that is YOU CANNOT, at least not in this universe.  A 24V 100A supply to an inverter, even with 100% efficiency will NEVER supply more than 2400W of output power.

Comment: From your answer the products in the market are bad. But very good companies in Nigeria like Felicity, Luminous, Blue Gate all sell this. This link has the Felicity product https://www.poiseenergy.com.ng/catalogue-sku/felicity-5kva-24v-inverter Is there something behind the scene untold?

Comment: I am not seeing anything related to 100A batteries in that link.  With almost all of these products, providing a properly designed and sized battery system is vital to using the inverter properly.

Comment: Are you saying the batteries are more than 100 A? The mainly used batteries here are 100amps. I have seen laws change. There maybe something new.

Comment: As I already said, most batteries will supply FAR more current than their rated capacity.  But doing so will damage them very quickly.  It's up to you to ensure that you use them properly.

Comment: A car engine usually takes around 100-150 Amps to start (depending on the size), but this typically takes less than 5 seconds. If you use currents this high for longer than a few seconds, you'll need _very_ thick cabling and a _very_ good battery heat management. The dangers of an exploding lead-acid battery are real.

Comment: @Jeswills: Higher capacity batteries are available, and you can connect more batteries in parallel to get higher capacity - I have four 225 Ah 6 V batteries on my boat, connected to give 450 Ah at 12 volts.

Answer (score 1):

The 100 Ampere Hour rating on the battery is a capacity specification, not a maximum current specification. In order to run an inverter that puts out 240 VAC at 16 Amps, you need to pull about 340 Amps on the 24 Volt side. This actually isn't unreasonable but only for a short period of time. In a case like that, you'll get roughly 15 minutes of power. On a lead acid car battery they may have an Ampere hour rating of 100 AH but a cold cranking ampere rating of 750 Amps. This means that the battery can deliver up to 750 Amps for short periods (30 seconds).